# Parametric spline regression after Gaussian process regression?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process, splines

I'm trying to develop a (functional) model to predict the output of a computer simulation. I've run a small set of experiments, varying the 4 predictors $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ via LHS, and calculated the output, $y$. The response is expected to be nonlinear, so traditional regression seems insufficient. As a starting point, I've fit a Gaussian Process to determine as obvious relationships, see below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The next step is to develop the actual functional model $y \approx f(a,b,c,d)$. I've been doing a lot of reading, and it seems spline regression might be the best approach, is there a better option?

If spline regression is the best approach, can anyone recommend an R package (or any other language) for this? I've tried a few, but CRAN is loaded with many "spline regression" packages, and it's difficult to identify which packages would work. Keeping in mind, I need to output the coefficients $\beta_i$ and the knots $x_i$.

If my approach is completely incorrect, any help or recommendations are very welcome.

Comment: What are the points with the upper and lower ticks shown on the graph? Are those the actual y points?

Comment: Yes, those are the data being fit, which is why they don't change from plot to plot (because the x-axis was held constant).

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a trend at all (a spline wouldn't help with that)

Comment: The "no trend" is because the experiments were design as space-filling. As a result, one of the simulations had a large $b$, small $c$, and large $d$. These effects combined causes the spike near $y$ = 20. I think the colored GP lines clearly show trends for $b$, $c$, and $d$.